# Tratar consulta mysql quando ids forem repetidos

Tags: php

Como posso proceder quando linhas com ids iguais em uma consulta no mysql fazer algo,

Preciso que... se linhas tiverem o mesmo id elas fiquem com uma cor,  se não de outra.

como no exemplo a baixo

```
$cmd = " SELECT *FROM cotacao ";
    $produtos = mysql_query($cmd);
    $total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);
    while ($linha = mysql_fetch_array($produtos)) {

$id_grupo = $linha['id_grupo'];


//se linha com mesmo id_grupos iguais
<tr style = 'background-color: yellow'>$id_grupos</tr>
//  senão 
<tr style = 'background-color: blue'>$id_grupos</tr>

 }
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Não funcionou não amigo...

Comment: fica todas as linha em azul.  minha consulta me retornou 5 linhas e entre as 5, duas com ids iguais, então só essas com ids iguais deveriam ficar com a a mesma cor  , e sim é inteiro

Comment: Conseguiu resolver o problema ?

Answer (score 1):

```
//INDEX.PHP

<?php

$array = [
    "one",
    "two",
    "three",
    "three",
    "four",
    "five",
    "five"
];

foreach ($array as $value) {
    echo "<p>$value</p>";
}
?>

//JAVASCRIPT

<script type="text/javascript">
    var elements         = document.getElementsByTagName("p"); //pego todos as tags "p" no meu caso
    var alreadyStylized  = []; //lista daqueles que já foram utilizados

    Array.from(elements).forEach((elem) => {
        //todos os que não se repetem ficam azul
        elem.style.background = "dodgerblue";

        //pego o texto/id do elemento atual
        var id = elem.textContent;
        //verifico se já foi estilizado
        if (alreadyStylized.indexOf(id) != -1) {
            //itero sobre todos novamente
            Array.from(elements).forEach((elem2) => {
                //porém verifico se o id confere
                if (elem2.textContent == id) {
                    //adiciona yellow para todos que tem o mesmo
                    //id/texto
                    elem2.style.background = "yellow";
                }
            })
        }
        //no final coloca o id daqueles que ja foram estilizados
        alreadyStylized = id;
    });
</script>
```

Me pergunto se poderia estar usando PHP para tudo, mas é preferível estilizar o conteúdo de uma pagina com javascript.

Se você por tudo isso dentro de um arquivo chamado index.php e executar vai aparecer isso:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Suporte por browsers `Array.from()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Suporte por browsers `Array.forEach()`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Fonte imagens: https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/

Comment: Parceiro da dando erro de sintax

Comment: Amigo é bem por ai.... mais eu não consigo e mudar a cor da linha da tabela dessa forma...